# How to change a modx revolution users class_key when newly created VIA the manager?

Tags: modx-revolution

I'm trying to change a new user's class_key value when they are created VIA the manager.

In a plugin that fires on the onUserSave event:

```
<?php

$uid = $_POST['id'];

$sql = "update modx_users set `class_key` = 'extUser' where id = $uid;";

$modx->log(modX::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR, 'query = ' . $sql);

$query = $modx->query($sql);

return;
```

Which works when you EDIT an EXISTING user, but does not work if you try to CREATE a NEW user.

Any thoughts on how to do this?

None of the system events look like they fire when a new user is created.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the user/create processor, you would need to listen for *OnUserFormSave* which is fired after saving the new user.

I haven't tested this, but in your plugin you have access to `$modx->event`. Log the output of this for the *OnUserFormSave* event, hopefully it should include a 'data' property containing the new user object. The object should contain the new user id.

Let me know how that goes!

**Update**

I've tested this out. As expected, you have access to the new user id, user object (and much more) in the `$modx->event` object:

```
if ($modx->event->name == 'OnUserFormSave') {

    // id of user you've just created
    $newUserId = $modx->event->name->params->id;

    // full modUser object is available here
    $newUserObj = $modx->event->name->params->user;

}
```

Comment: I don't think the user is saved at that point, if you try to get the event->user reference it's empty~ if we print_r(the $modx->event) there is no data property

Comment: The user has definitely been saved at that point. 'OnUserFormSave' is fired immediately after saving, see the user/create processor: https://github.com/modxcms/revolution/blob/master/core/model/modx/processors/security/user/create.class.php

Answer (score 0):

In plugin with OnUserSave event:

```
$scriptProperties['user']->set('class_key','extUser');
```

That's it nothing more.

You cannot call

```
$scriptProperties['user']->save();
```

in OnUserSave as other examples elsewhere have shown.

Comment: Does that save the class_key to the database, or just set it temporarily at runtime?

Comment: It will be saved to the database when it returns back to the OnUserSave event.  Calling ->save() inside this event will cause an error.